# Notifications are not shown when the app is killed

Tags: android, kotlin

My task is to make every day notification schedule at a certain time. At the moment I have the current implementation:

```
fun scheduleRepeatingRTCNotification(context: Context, hour: Int, min: Int) {
    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    
    val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    alarmIntentRTC = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        ALARM_TYPE_RTC,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    alarmManagerRTC = context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManagerRTC!!.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC,
        calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntentRTC
    )
}
```

Also my broadcast receiver class:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {


override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val intentToRepeat = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    intentToRepeat.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        NotificationHelper.ALARM_TYPE_RTC,
        intentToRepeat,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    
    val repeatedNotification: Notification =
        buildLocalNotification(context, pendingIntent).build()
    
    NotificationHelper.getNotificationManager(context)
        .notify(NotificationHelper.ALARM_TYPE_RTC, repeatedNotification)
}
```

This code works except when the app is killed, when the app is killed the notification appears only when the app is started. Is there any way to make the notification appear even when the app is killed ? I tried Work Manager, Services, the same behavior everywhere.

Comment: Did you define "BroadcastReceiver" in the Android Manifest file as a Service?

Comment: @MustafaYanık No, i defined it as "receiver", just like this
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".view.main.AlarmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote"/>

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but because the app's process can be killed as soon as ``onReceive`` ends, maybe the ``notify`` call is being queued up, and it doesn't have time to execute? There's some recommendations for longer-running tasks here that might be worth trying: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#effects-process-state also if the device is sleeping, you might need a wakelock (e.g. calling ``startService`` can fail because the device can sleep before the service actually starts). I'm guessing you've logged to make sure ``onReceive`` is being called?

Comment: @cactustictacs i just checked it queued up and don't wake receiver, so when app is killed onReceive is not called at all, what can i do with this ?

Comment: Try ``AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`` for your alarm type when you call ``setRepeating`` - the docs say "If an alarm is delayed (by system sleep, for example, for non _WAKEUP alarm types), a skipped repeat will be delivered as soon as possible" which sounds like what you're seeing? It also says "as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact" so if you're expecting an alarm at a specific time each day, you might not get it - you're supposed to use a one-time exact alarm, and while you're handling that in the receiver, schedule the next one